# How to solve a math expression with proper significant digits?

Tags: significant-figures

I've talked with my friend from chemistry about this question, and looked all over the internet for like hours now, and couldn't find anything that would help in my situation.

The problem is this:

$$\frac{(19-9.25)}{(7.4 \times 2.26)}$$

So right away I know that the uncertainty in the addition is with the $19$, at $\pm 1$. The numerator would have $2$ significant digits from the $7.4$, but as the final answer is $.582944989$, do I use one significant digit from the numerator and make it $6 \times 10^{-1}$? Or does the overall division cancel out the subtraction somehow, so

$$\frac{9.75}{(7.4 \times 2.26)}?$$

I looked all around, and all of the examples I've found never had a whole number without a decimal, or never had one in an equation like this. Appreciate any  help.

Answer (score 2):

For the record, no scientist actually uses significant figures. They use error bars because you can quantify how big the uncertainty is beyond it is in such and such decimal place.

There should be one significant figure. Because the $9.75$ in the numerator has one significant figure (before rounding). The extra precision in 7.4 doesn't mean much because of the large uncertainty in the numerator.

Try this:
$19$ is really $19\pm 1$. $7.4$ is really $7.4\pm 0.1$.

For the uncertainty in $19$, you could have:
$$\frac{20-9.25}{7.4 \times 2.6}\approx 0.643$$ on the upper end and
$$\frac{18-9.25}{7.4 \times 2.6}\approx 0.523$$ on the lower end. From this,
you can see the answer should be $0.6\pm 0.1$.

For the uncertainty in $7.4$ you have:
$$\frac{19-9.25}{7.3 \times 2.6}\approx 0.591$$ on the upper end and
$$\frac{19-9.25}{7.5 \times 2.6}\approx 0.575$$ on the lower end.
Based on the error here, the answer would be $0.58\pm 0.01$.

Notice that the precision is much worse for assuming that the error is in the number $19$. This is why significant figures work.

Answer (score -2):

As a rule you can only be as certain as your least amount of significant figures. If you are doing only a rough calculation or homework question, my teacher usually suggests that you use exact values where possible and round to 3 sf for the final answer. If you are being more accurate you need to follow the rule scritly however

Comment: This is correct for multiplication and division. The question given is more complex than this.